# Search for a folder only for a certain level (3 sub directories only)

Tags: ruby, windows, file-search

Currently I am searching for a '.svn' folder inside a path using the below code :

```
require 'find'
svn_folders = []
@folder_path = 'C:\my_repositories\'
Find.find(@folder_path) do |path|
  svn_folders << path if path =~ /.*\.svn$/
end
```

The above code will search all the folders inside `@folder_path` and lists me with the `svn_folders` path.

But, the big problem is that these folders are a big (50GB +) so searching for the '.svn' folder takes a lot of time to search.

Question : Is it possible to search only for certain level of sub folders, 3 sub folders in my case?

Example : 
If my folder path is `C:\my_repositories`

I would like to search 3 layers (sub folders) down i.e, till `C:\my_repositories\project_name\repository_name\repository`

and would not like to search beneath the folder named repository.

Any suggestions would be really helpful. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Here is the [way](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/201746) ..  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't it just

```
Dir.glob("*/*/*/.svn")
```